# Best way to check if value is integer ? Coldfusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, integer, coldfusion-9, isnumeric

I have fields to test and make sure they only accept `integers`. There is few functions but I wasn't sure which one is the best. First I tried `isValid("integer",value)` but I have discovered that "1,5" will be accepted as an integer. So then I tried `isNumeric(value)` but this will accept values like `1.5`. I'm wondering what should be the best way to check for integers? Maybe two combine these two functions like:

```
<cfif isValid("integer",value) AND isNumeric(value)>
```

Or there is better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
value = replace(value, ',', '', 'all');
numberIsInteger = isNumeric(value) && round(value) == value ? true : false;
```

**Note**
People often include commas in large numbers such as 1,000,000.  `isNumeric` will return false for that string, as will the refind function in the other answers.

Comment: Way we use round? Is that better than isValid() ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @espresso_coffee `isNumeric()` accepts floating-point numbers. He uses `round()` to cut off the precision and then compares the value to itself to make sure the number is a whole number (integer).

Comment: As a side note: This function doesn't check the integer range. This could result in errors if you validate inputs to put them into an `int` field in a database, which usually declare `int` with a size of 4 Byte.

Comment: I have function that checks each value and checks the range. In that case solution above should be the best for my function. Thank you!

Comment: @espresso_coffee According to my test script https://trycf.com/gist/fab1104a3a9074434ff336630dd5ffd1, this method fails that following values: 192292121121121212.1   2147483648    "#CHR(28)#00501#CHR(28)#"    " 123 "   " 123"   "123 "   "1,234"   and "07,20,1969".  Built-in CFQueryParam & CFParam functions also disagree with this answer and will throw CFErrors.  Also, don't forget that VAL("1,234") will only return "1".

Comment: @JamesMoberg What is you suggestion? Which solution will be better?

Answer (score 6):

## cfscript

```
// Returns if the provided value is a signed integer up to 32 Bit.
function isINT(any value) {

    return (
        isSimpleValue(ARGUMENTS.value) &&
        (reFind("^\-?[0-9]{1,10}$", ARGUMENTS.value) > 0) &&
        (ARGUMENTS.value <= 2147483647) &&
        (ARGUMENTS.value >= -2147483648)
    );
}
```

## cftag

```
<cffunction name="isINT" access="public" output="false" returnType="boolean"
    hint="Returns if the provided value is a signed integer up to 32 Bit.">

    <cfargument name="value" type="any" required="true">

    <cfreturn (
        isSimpleValue(ARGUMENTS.value) and
        (reFind("^\-?[0-9]{1,10}$", ARGUMENTS.value) gt 0) and
        (ARGUMENTS.value lte 2147483647) and
        (ARGUMENTS.value gte -2147483648)
    )>
</cffunction>
```

- `isSimpleValue` making sure the input is a primitive type (by CF means), because all numbers are considered simple values in CF (string conversion)
- `reFind` regular expression checking digits-only (with or without sign), minimum of one digit, maximum of ten digits (implicit call of `toString` here)
- check the range, all numeric types fit into 4 Bytes, thus no need to "upgrade" the type (as you would need to with BigInteger, BigDecimal etc.)

If you don't need the range check for 4 Byte integers, @DanBracuk posted an answer with a function that performs around 5-6 times faster than this one.

Comment: If you use this in real life, note the change to my answer regarding commas.

Comment: Testing for isSimpleValue is a good addition and will prevent array/struct objects from throwing an error. I don't often pass these types of values to the function, but you never know if/when a parameter could be overwritten and cause problems. (I'm updating my personal UDF to include this.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the isInteger UDF that I prefer using:

```
function isInteger(num){
    return YesNoFormat(refind("^-?\d+$", num) AND VAL(num) LTE 2147483647 AND VAL(num) GTE -2147483648);
}
```

Here are some tests to determine how it functions and compares against the various built-in functions.

https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/fab1104a3a9074434ff336630dd5ffd1

View the results using TryCF.com

https://trycf.com/gist/fab1104a3a9074434ff336630dd5ffd1

Comment: Why `ucase` and `YesNoFormat`? Change `refind("^-?\d+$", num)` to `refind("^-?\d+$", num) gt 0` and it stays boolean.

Comment: `GTE -2147483647` doesn't seem correct. `-2147483648` still fits into the signed integer range of 32 Bits.

Comment: Sorry. I had taken this from a visual output test I was used. Native booleans values were dumped in uppercase and YesNoFormat values were a mixed-cased text string. I had used UCase to enforce the same visual style. (I think this was when using CF9.)

Comment: If you use this in real life, note the change to my answer regarding commas.

Comment: @DanBracuk This UDF evaluates the value without any modification or translation attempt.  The strings "07,20,1969" and "1,234" are not a valid integers according to CFParam or CFQueryParam... so testing a modified value & then using the original value will result in an error. On my form-based inputs, I intentionally use javascript to validate & limit min/max values (and prevent commas from being typed or pasted into the field.)

Comment: I still thought it worth mentioning for the benefit of people who read this thread in the future.